# Custom font not working in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to use a font from google fonts in my app. [Here is the font](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Orbitron&query=orbitron).

I have placed the .ttf file in `app/fonts`.

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": ["./app/fonts"]
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
            "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "flow-typed": "^2.0.0",
        "immutable": "^3.8.1",
        "react": "~15.4.1",
        "react-native": "0.42.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
        "redux": "^3.6.0",
        "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
        "eslint": "^3.17.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.3",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.1",
        "flow-bin": "^0.42.0",
        "jest": "19.0.2",
        "jest-cli": "^19.0.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
        "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7"
    }
}
```

then ran `react-native link`.

Then use the font in my app:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Width from '../width/Width'
import Shape from '../shape/Shape'
import Height from '../height/Height'
import Thickness from '../thickness/Thickness'

export const Volcalc = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>SHAPE</Text>
    <Shape />
    <Text style={styles.text}>HEIGHT</Text>
    <Height />
    <Text style={styles.text}>WIDTH</Text>
    <Width />
    <Text style={styles.text}>THICKNESS</Text>
    <Thickness />
  </View>
)

const $mainColor = '#00d1b2'
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: $mainColor
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'Orbitron'
  }
}
```

In android it doesn't show the new font but has no error. In ios it has error:

> Unrecognised font family "Orbitron"

What am I doing wrong?

How do I find out the EXACT value to place in `fontFamily: 'xxx'`?

Answer (score 66):

Many answers are here for custom font in **react-native for version < 0.60**

For those who are using **react-native version > 0.60** , **`'rnpm' is deprecated`** and custom fonts will not work.

Now, in order to add custom font in react-native version > 0.60 you will have to :

1- Create a file named `react-native.config.js` in the root folder of your project.

2- add this in that new file

```
module.exports = {
project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
},
assets: ['./assets/fonts']
};
```

3- run `react-native link` command in the root project path.

4- run it using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` command

**UPDATE for Step-3**

---

**For those running on **react-native version >= 0.69.x**, Since `link` is deprecated so `react-native link` will not work anymore,
the command `react-native link` is replaced by `npx react-native-asset`.**

More info about the release can be seen here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/releases/tag/v8.0.0

Comment: Appart from the above, I had to run `react-native run-android` again to see the fonts working.

Comment: This is the answer that solves my problem that I've worked for about 2 hours. Is there a page where we can track differences between versions?

Comment: @yunusemremeral You can track differences between versions here https://react-native-community.github.io/rn-diff-purge/

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I followed the steps but nothing is happening on running react-native link. No log no info. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @ShivamTiwari  what version are you using of react native?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.5

Comment: @ShivamTiwari Have you created the react-native.config.js file ? and also cross check the path of the fonts before running react-native link command.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Yes, I have created the file. Let me cross check the path again.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Yes, There was path issue. Thanks for time buddy.

Comment: @ShivamTiwari Glad I could Help.

Comment: Note: Even after autolinking is introduced, to add fonts to your react native, you still **need** to run `react-native link`

Comment: This worked for me too, the initial problem was I was having the fonts in a src/assets/fonts and forgot to add the ./src

Comment: Can you run 'react-native link'  in an expo managed workflow? Or can you only use custom fonts in an ejected or bare workflow?

Answer (score 47):

In case somebody is reading this because their setup is fine and custom fonts work on iOS and in *some cases* don't work on Android:

Additionally to the installation answers given above - make sure you are not setting font `fontWeight` parameter (or other extra font transformation in styles). In my case it 'broke' custom font, so I had to **add and use font ttf with variants** (like Roboto-Thin, Roboto-Bold etc) in stead of setting bold in styles.

Also worth to notice: Manuel Hernandez found out in comment below that it is possible to use i.e. `fontWeight:800` in stead of `fontWeight:'bold'`.

Comment: This worked for me, but I subsequently found that I could replace fontWeight:'bold' with fontWeight:800'

Comment: Worked for me, but i wonder what is the underlying reason for this

Comment: I would like to add to this that react-native-elments caused this issue for me if i used their built-in h1, h2, etc properties.

Comment: Using react-native 0.69.1 - on IOS variable weight fonts and fontWeight worked, but did not on Android. I had to remove those variable weight ( and the fontWeight style ) fonts and add the specific weight fonts - then it worked on android.

Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 10):

Fonts in React Native are handled in the same way as in native applications, as assets to the native project.

In iOS, you have to add them as resources. You can have a good description [here](https://medium.com/@dabit3/adding-custom-fonts-to-react-native-b266b41bff7f#.ri1ph8j6p).

In Android you have to add them as assets. [Here](https://medium.com/@gattermeier/custom-fonts-in-react-native-for-android-b8a331a7d2a7#.vkk8etu6d) you can see how to.

Also note that the name of the font in iOS is the one contained in the metadata of the .ttf file, whereas in Android they are matched by the file name and several suffixes.

Comment: Thanks. How do I find out the android font name (suffixes)?

Comment: The suffix corresponds to the font attributes (bold, italics...) and the name is arbitrary. You can see a few examples in the article.

Answer (score 6):

I found out that for some fonts you need to run `npx react-native-asset` in order to make it work on Android. If it's not working within 3rd party components you have to add `fontWeight: 'normal'` to override some default values.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you've linked correctly or your app just isn't loading the new resource.

Add

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": ["./app/fonts"]
}
```

to your package.json.

Then

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install && react-native link
```

If things go right, search inside `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/` for your custom font.
If you see it, you linked successfully.

Similarly for iOS, run XCode and expand Resource dropdown for your custom font.

Kill your emulator and re-try

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Unsure why you need to delete node_modules in this command. The command should simply be 'react-native link'.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the fonts are lowercase only and follow this pattern: fontname.ttf, fontname_bold.ttf, fontname_light.ttf, fontname_bold_italic.ttf

Comment: why lowercase only?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this problem is

Remove the fontWeight property in styles and it will work!

I removed it and immediately got my poppins fontstyle.

Answer (score 3):

To find the exact value to use as your fontFamily, you can run the project from xcode after adding the following code to your AppDelegate.m file in xcode. You'll see a list of fonts in the output section in xcode.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

Helpful link for adding custom fonts: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: This was critical in helping me track down the issue. For some reason my font names were having special characters removed from the fontFamily name. For instance, my font file was named `Proxima-Nova-Soft-Bold.otf` and I was using `Proxima-Nova-Soft-Bold` as the fontFaimily name. But, when I checked the font family name that iOS needs using this logging, it was looking for the fontFamily name of `ProximaNovaSoft-Bold`. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

**The path could be incorrectly linked -**

The path where react-native link stored the fonts was - `android/src/main/assets/fonts`

**Path should be -**  `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`

Even with react-native version 0.62 this problem exits

Answer (score 2):

Removing default style properties like fontWeight also solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue. All my font setup was fine, all of the custom fonts were working okay except one in IOS. [image]

if you look into the screen shot you will find that the full name is actually not exactly as the file name.

You can also list all your apps available font names by adding the following code in appdelegate.m.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]){
   NSLog(@"%@", family);
   for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family]){
       NSLog(@"  %@", name);
   }
}
```

you will have to use the name that will be printed on xcode log for ios. i did something like this

```
Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'Agrandir-TextBold' : 'Agrandir-Bold'
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to do some conditional styling based on OS

```
<Text style={{fontFamily:'Nunito-Bold',fontWeight: Platform.OS === 'android' ? '':'bold' }}>Some text goes here</Text>
```

because the type of font I'm using appears to be very thin on iOS, even though the style is `bold`, and my custom font won't work on Android if I specify `fontWeight`.

This is working as of React Native `0.70.0`.

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me.

1. Add your fonts to the `yourproject/assets` folder.
2. Then add `"rnpm": {"assets": ["./assets/fonts/"]}` to your package.json file.
3. Run `react-native link`
4. Check if the fonts are added to `yourproject/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`(for android)
5. Must run `react-native run-android` to get your changes.(most people forget to run this)

Answer (score 1):

Adding my two cents here because it took me a good 4 hours to figure out: check if your font is "Valid". On Mac you can do this in Font Book > File > Validate font. React-Native link will not throw any errors and neither will Android Studio or Xcode. So if your font is corrupted it will simply be ignored and you have no idea why. To make it valid I exported it from Font Book and ran the react-native link command again. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

My fonts would display perfectly for android, but would not show up for ios. I tried everything and nothing really worked for me, until I tried seeing if my other fonts installed within my assets folder would display. The other fonts did work. So I decided to delete the font that I wanted to use (gotham-medium) and re-downloaded a different file of that same font from the internet and then included that into my code. Now it works! Praise God! I spent 2 days trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

**It's working for me in 2023.**

1. First, make sure you are up to version 0.16+ with react-native.
2. Your fonts should be *.ttf or *.otf files and must be located in:
   `/projectname/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`
3. **(!important)** List item Make sure the fonts are lowercase only and follow this    pattern:
   `fontname.ttf, fontname_bold.ttf, fontname_light.ttf, fontname_bold_italic.ttf`
4. You can add your styles like this: `{fontFamily: ‘fontname’}`
5. And should see the new fonts applied after running:

`yarn android` or, `npx run android` or, `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question and I'm doing it this way it's working for me

open this path

```
<Project Name>android\app\src\main\assets
```

then in the `assets` folder create a new folder named  `fonts`
in the fonts, folder add a font file with the `.ttf` extension

then go to your App.js and add like this

**App.js**

```
 <View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}>
  <Text style={{
    fontFamily: 'your_font_file_name',
  }}>Hello, world!</Text>
</View>
```

Maybe this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

My project is specific to the Android, we don't have ios. I've tried all options in the answer but it didn't solve the issue and found out the problem is with `npx react-native link` command. It actually loops all the projects first ios and then android.

I've tried `npx react-native link --platforms android` but it didn't work.

So, I deleted the ios directory inside the project and ran the command `npx react-native link` and it successfully linked the new assets for android. You can simply restore the ios directory again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me the fonts loaded fine when building the app locally but they failed to load when the app was built by our CI pipeline.

It turns out that when I changed the casing of the filenames to match the iOS identifier the **casing change was not picked up by git**. It seems to ignore case changes in filenames.
Check if the file names in your remote repository match the file names on your machine.
There is probably a more straig forward way of updating the filenames on git but I just moved the font folders, commmited and moved them back:

```
mv assets/fonts assets/fonts2
mv android/app/src/main/assets android/app/src/main/assets2
git commit -m "Make git pick up on correct font casing - part 1"
mv assets/fonts2 assets/fonts
mv android/app/src/main/assets2 android/app/src/main/assets
git commit -m "Make git pick up on correct font casing - part 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be of help to anyone.

But when I tried all the suggestions above and nothing was working, I simply ran

expo doctor --fix-dependencies

All my dependencies were then updated to the required and compatible versions, and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me bellow steps working after allots of try

Note: before I solved my file name was **react-native.config.js**
Inside my file bellow code was there

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
 module.exports = {
  project: {
  ios: {},
  android: {}, // grouped into "project"
 },
assets: ['./assets/fonts/'], // where you put your custom fonts
};
```

Solution:

1. Just change the **react-native.config.js** to *react-native-config.js*
2. npx react-native link
3. re run your project
4. npx react-native start
5. npx react-native run-android
6. Happy coding

Comment: npx react-native link will not work above 0.70 use npx react-native-asset instead

Answer (score 0):

In some fonts, `fontWeight` causes the font to not render.
In my case if I used any `fontWeight` more than `600`, it was not rendering my custom font.

I did following to render my custom font:

1. Placed font files in `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`.
2. Used the font in React Native component with `fontFamily` property and `fontWeight` upto `600`.

```
fontWeight: '600',
fontFamily: 'IBMPlexSerif-Bold',
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run this command in my /fonts folder:

```
$ for file in "$arg"*.{ttf,otf}; do fc-scan --format "%{postscriptname}\n" $file; done
```

To get the postcript name format of the fonts. Then rename all the fonts accordingly.

And finally, restart the app with :

```
$ npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Tbh, I do not understand why using postscript name resolved my problem. I'm sure it's not only restarting and cleaning cache that resolved the issue because I already restart and reset cache multiple time before.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are a little lacking in the ios aspect of this issue so I'll try to address that with this answer specifically for react-native `0.69`.

1. Create an assets file inside the `src` directory of your react native project and add the font files there. Ensure they are lowercase file names and only have underscores as special characters **with no spaces**.
2. Create a `react-native.config.js` file in the root of your react native project with the following contents, or just add the path to your existing assets array in this file.

```js
  module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/<yourAssetsDirectory>'],
  };
```

3. Run `npx react-native-asset`[see HarshitMadhav's answer for alternative linking commands for react-native versions older than `0.69`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57248895/9995318).
   You should see the following output if it works correctly:

```bash
    info Linking otf assets to Android project
    info Linking otf assets to iOS project
```

4. To ensure the linking has worked in ios, check `$yourAppRootDirectory/ios/$appName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` for changes. Searching for the name of your font in lowercase should turn it up.
5. Add the font family in lowercase to a `fontFamily` attribute in your React Native project, ensure no other font properties are applied (to rule them out from being the cause of the font not appearing) and reload the app using the `ios-build` command.