# Can't Change Font Family (React-Native)

Tags: css, react-native

I'm pretty new to react-native and don't have much experience with CSS. I'm simply trying to change the font family to helvetica. I've tried multiple times and nothing changes

This is my css code:

```
import {StyleSheet} from "react-native";

export default StyleSheet.create({

  header: {
    backgroundColor:'#004D4D',
    height: 35,
  },

  headerT: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  body: {
    backgroundColor:'#E6FFFF',
    flex:1,
  },

})
```

This is the page I'm trying to amend

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import styles from "../style/css";

class HomeScreen extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.body}>


        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerT}>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>


      </View>

    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

This is my directory

[image]

Comment: And how do you know it's not working? Does your device has this font already?

Comment: It's not working because everytime i refresh, the font never changes. I have tried multiple different fonts as well

Answer (score 2):

A list for avaliable react-native fonts: https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-fonts

If you are using Android, Helvetica won't work directly, you need to use custom font.

Here is an article for [Custom Fonts in React Native for iOS & Android Builds](https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add the fonts to the assets folder by downloading whichever font you want for example You want ** Helvetica** then you will need to download `Helvetica.ttf` file for it.

After that in your `package.json` you need to add this following lines :-

```js
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
},
```

Then we tell react native to link those font files for us.

On Android if you look in the file path `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/` you should see your fonts have been copied over.

On IOS it is added in `Info.plist file`.

Now Simply add a fontFamily property with your font name.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use fontWeight? If yes, try removing it (can cause problems on Android, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58765980 ).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30025185)